# SQL INSERT with parameter as query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, parameters

How can I insert parameter with value from database.
I have some field and I should insert value from this database + 1 (with plus one)

For example

```
myCommand.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO GAMES (GAME_NR, GAME_PLAYER_ID, GAME_NRONTABLE, GAME_ROLE_ID) " &
            " VALUES (@game_nr, @game_player_id, @game_nrontable, @game_role_id)"

'Example
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@game_nr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = **"(SELECT MAX(GAME_NR) FROM GAMES)" + 1**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the parameter, you can try following code.

```
myCommand.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO GAMES (GAME_NR, GAME_PLAYER_ID, GAME_NRONTABLE, GAME_ROLE_ID) " &
            " VALUES ((SELECT MAX(GAME_NR) + 1 FROM GAMES), @game_player_id, @game_nrontable, @game_role_id)"
```

But it looks like a primary key of the table. If Game_Nr is pr, You should use auto-inc. identity, then you don't need this param.

It will be.

```
myCommand.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO GAMES (GAME_PLAYER_ID, GAME_NRONTABLE, GAME_ROLE_ID) " &
                " VALUES (@game_player_id, @game_nrontable, @game_role_id)"
```

Comment: How would that behave in a multi-user environment? For example, current `MAX(GAME_NR) = 100`. Then you and me run `INSERT` you suggest, and for both of us `MAX + 1 = 101`. If `GAME_NR` was a primary key ... hm?

Comment: thank Littlefoot for warning me, I will edit my answer. But I don't agree with you. I think, there will first execute generate 101 then 102.

Comment: Until user COMMITs changes (i.e. that INSERT statement), everyone else, who selects `MAX(GAME_NR)` would see the old value. So, if there were 20 users who did `INSERT INTO` with `MAX(GAME_NR) + 1`, all of them would want to insert 101, but only the first one who commits would succeed. Everyone else's attempt would fail because of primary key violation. That's why, generally speaking, MAX + 1 is a bad idea. Though, if `AUTOCOMMIT` is enabled, database would commit itself so those problems would, probably, be avoided. Personally, I prefer choosing when to commit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  You make `GAME_NR` and auto-incremented primary key:

```
create table games (
    game_nr int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Then you do the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO GAMES (GAME_PLAYER_ID, GAME_NRONTABLE, GAME_ROLE_ID)
    VALUES (@game_player_id, @game_nrontable, @game_role_id);
```

Let the database do the work.